# Palette for pasting matrix templates into a notebook

Tags: notebooks, palettes

How I can build a palette of matrices?. So, I would like a palette with a 3x3 square matrix, a square matrix 4x4, 1x3 row matrix, 1x4 matrix row, column matrix 3x1 and 4x1 column matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Using `PasteButton` with a matrix containing the desired matrix is one option.

```
PasteButton["3x3 Matrix", MatrixForm@( {
    {\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder],\[Placeholder]},
    {\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder],\[Placeholder]},
    {\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder],\[Placeholder]}
   } )]
PasteButton["1x3 Matrix", MatrixForm@( {
    {\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder],\[Placeholder]}
   } )]
PasteButton["3x1 Matrix", MatrixForm@( {
    {\[Placeholder]}, {\[Placeholder]},{\[Placeholder]}
   } )]
```

The 4x4, 1x4, and 4x1 matrices can be made in an analogous fashion.  To put them in a palette:

```
CreatePalette[{PasteButton["3x3 Matrix", 
   MatrixForm@({{\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]}, {\
\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]}, {\[Placeholder], \
\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]}})],
  PasteButton["1x3 Matrix", 
   MatrixForm@({{\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]}})],
  PasteButton["3x1 Matrix", 
   MatrixForm@({{\[Placeholder]}, {\[Placeholder]}, \
{\[Placeholder]}})]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Basic Math Assistant" palette built into the last few versions does most of what you need, except that it starts from a 2 by 2 matrix and builds rows and columns from there.

[image]